# Run results from call

Tags: r, api

I try to run [this](https://rpubs.com/cenuno/USAspendingAPI) example script but when I type this command I receive the following error

```
austin_tx <- city_state("AUSTIN", "TEXAS")

Error in if (this.clean.resp$page_metadata$has_next_page == FALSE) { : 
  argument is of length zero
```

any idea why this happens?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Up front, the API has changed.

> *Endpoint has been removed. Please refer to https://api.usaspending.gov/docs/endpoints for currently supported endpoints, or https://github.com/fedspendingtransparency/usaspending-api to report an issue.*

How I found this:

```r
> debug(GET_all_pages) # the error indicates code found in this function
> austin_tx <- city_state("AUSTIN", "TEXAS")
> austin_tx <- city_state("AUSTIN", "TEXAS")
debugging in: GET_all_pages(PATH = "/api/v1/transactions/", QUERY = list(place_of_performance__city_name = CITY_NAME, 
    place_of_performance__state_name = STATE_NAME))
debug at #1: { ...
Browse[2]> n                                              # 'n' --> step to the next expression
debug at #3: pages <- list()
Browse[2]> n
debug at #5: url <- modify_url("https://api.usaspending.gov", path = PATH, 
    query = QUERY)
Browse[2]> n
debug at #10: raw.resp <- GET(url)
Browse[2]> n
debug at #11: if (http_type(raw.resp) != "application/json") {
    stop("API did not return json. Check 'status code = 200'", 
        call. = FALSE)
}
Browse[2]> n
debug at #15: this.char.resp <- rawToChar(raw.resp$content)
Browse[2]> n
debug at #17: this.clean.resp <- fromJSON(this.char.resp, flatten = TRUE)
Browse[2]> n
```

Since we know that this is the object causing the problem, I stop stepping here and take a look at the variable.

```r
Browse[2]> str(this.clean.resp)
List of 1
 $ detail: chr "Endpoint has been removed. Please refer to https://api.usaspending.gov/docs/endpoints for currently supported e"| __truncated__
```

The doc you referenced is out of date and needs to be updated per the instructions at https://api.usaspending.gov/docs/endpoints.

Comment: Thank you very much. Could I make one more question as I am new in the field. A different option is to download the databaset from here https://files.usaspending.gov/database_download/. I downloaded the small file. Is there any way to read this database using R commands as a dataframe without the need to use first the postgres option?

Comment: Since the file description says it is a *"PostgreSQL Dump Archive"*, the answer is **no**. I don't know of any tool that enables access to the raw dump format of postgres (or any DBMS, I suspect). However, you could start up a [docker postgres](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres/) image, import the dump archive into that, and access the local DBMS that way. (If you have never used docker, then ... that might not be for you.)

Comment: you mean "that might not be for you." in case I don't know how to use docker option?

Comment: The use of `docker` is not gargantuan, but it's not always intuitive to everybody, so I tend to make the recommendation with caution. SO is not really a good site for tutorials to help with that, and I don't have a link readily available. That's all.

Comment: Having said that, I downloaded the subset (small) zip, and note that the first `.dat.gz` file I opened looks to be a space- or tab-delimited file, in which case you might be able to import them manually. Unfortunately, it has a non-standard last few lines, suggesting that you'll get (at best) warnings during import. I don't know if those should all go into one table or multiple tables, so unfortunately it might be "juice not worth the squeeze".

Comment: But if you are comfortable enough using (or willing to learn) docker, then I think that is perhaps your best bet: pull a `postgres:12` (or `:latest`) image, start it with something like `docker run -d -p "5432:5432" --name mypg -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mysecretpassword -e POSTGRES_DB=usaspending postgres:12`. Then follow the usaspending instructions pdf on its suggested use of `pg_restore` (from within the docker container, likely using a volume mount) to import into a database. Then use R's `DBI` and `odbc` packages to connect to the postgres instace you just created.

Comment: Hi thank you it was very helpful. Please could I ask you if you have experience with api if you could take a look to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66934948/receive-data-for-contracts-using-api?noredirect=1#comment118320097_66934948?